# Is there a way to make custom icons in an editable cell clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I have a custom editor which adds increment & decrement icons to the cell on render (onRendered callback). Upon clicking on a the cell and then on either icon however, the icon's onclick event does not fire. How could I detect clicks on the icons within the cell?

[image: Table UI]

```
//  inside the custom editor
// ....

//  add steppers
//  `onclick` does not run
let decBtn = $('<a onclick="console.log(\'b\')" class="dec" uk-icon="icon: minus"></a>');
let incBtn = $('<a onclick="console.log(\'a\')" class="inc" uk-icon="icon: plus"></a>');

input.attr('type', 'number');
input.css({
    'padding': '5px 20% 5px',
    'margin': '0 auto',
    'width': '100%',
    'boxSizing': 'border-box',
    'textAlign': 'center',
})
.val(value);

onRendered(function() {
    let parent = cell.getElement();

    $(parent).append(decBtn);
    $(parent).append(incBtn);

    $(parent).on('click', 'a.inc', (e) => { console.log(e.target) }) //  doesn't run

    input.focus();
    input.css('height', '100%');
});
/// ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/23m8y96x/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I reproduced my issue in a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/23m8y96x/

Comment: It looks like the `cellClick` event captures the click, so it never reaches your custom listener.  The first thing that comes to mind would be created a custom formatter instead of a custom editor.  The formatter would always display the - and + buttons, but I think that it would work how you are looking to do it.

Comment: That worked quite well thanks!